# Java Getting each int in Output of Array to have commas?

Tags: java, sorting

I have the output of my array that looks like `123611` (example numbers).
I am trying to get the output to be nicely formatted `1,2,3,6,11`

I have not been around Java too much and I cannot remember how to go about doing this. Thanks!!

Here is my code:

```
int array3[] = { 1, 2, 3, 6, 11 };

for (int i = 0; i < array3.length; i++)
    System.out.print(array3[i]);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use Streams available from Java 8,
Note here I'm using the integer wrapper class Integer, not the primitive type **int**

```
Integer array3[] = { 1, 2, 3, 6, 11 };

System.out.println(Stream.of(array3)
 .collect(Collectors.mapping(String::valueOf, Collectors.joining(",")))
);
```

As @Jelaby mentioned, it's better to use map(), which converts each Integer to String first, then join it

```
Integer array3[] = { 1, 2, 3, 6, 11 };

System.out.println(Stream.of(array3)
                         .map(String::valueOf)
                         .collect( Collectors.joining(",")));
```

Comment: Good idea. You can get an `IntStream` 
from an `int` array with `Arrays.stream()`, and I would say that using `map()` or `mapToObj()` to transform the stream is more idiomatic than using a mapping collector. For example:  `Arrays.stream(array3).mapToObj(String::valueOf).collect(Collectors.joining(","))` (if using `Integer` instead of `int` you'd use `map` instead of `mapToObj`).

Comment: Oh cool, I didn't know about mapToObj method, Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You simply need to print them as well =)

```
for(int i=0; i< array3.length; i++) 
    System.out.print(array3[i] + (i <array3.length-1 ? ",":"") );
```

This is will leave the trailing comma off, and print one between each entry

Answer (score 1):

Here is an easy way to do this:

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class SO {
  public static void main(String[] args){
    int[] a = {1,2,3,6,11};
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(a));
  }
}
```

This outputs:

```
[1, 2, 3, 6, 11]
```

Or you can strip out the chars you don't want like this:

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(a).replaceAll("\\[|\\]|\\s", ""));
```

Which outputs:

```
1,2,3,6,11
```

Answer (score 0):

You can print `,` after each element except last one using this loop

```
for (int i = 0; i < array3.length - 1; i++)
    System.out.print(array3[i] + ", ");
```

and later print last element of array without `,` after it.

```
System.out.println(array3[array3.length - 1]);
```

---

Or just use

```
String arrStr = Arrays.toString(array3);//will produce "[1, 2, 3, 6, 11]"
System.out.println(arrStr);
//if you want to remove [...] brackets you can substring them with
System.out.println(arrStr.substring(1,arrStr.length()-1));
```

Answer (score 0):

I would bet this is what you're looking for:

```
Arrays.toString(array3);
```

The output is:

```
[1, 2, 3, 6, 11]
```

If you don't want the square brackets, just strip them.

Answer (score 0):

```
int array3[] = { 1, 2, 3, 6, 11 };
String s ="";
for (int i = 0; i < array3.length-1; i++){
    s +=array3[i]+", ";
}
s +=array3[array3.length-1];
System.out.print(s);
```

is essentially the same as `Array.toString()` but without [],
and doesn't use `if` statment or ternary `(?:)` in each iteration to check if it's the last element.In genaral, building a String first, is a better practice, because its faster and you get a string to process, `System.out` and its gone.

Comment: Use StringBuilder like stringBuilder.append(), because String is immutable every time it creates